# ¿Cómo activar un botón desde otro botón en el mismo Activity? Android Studio

Tags: android, botón, activity

Como puedo hacerle para que al presionar un botón, este se esconda o deshabilite y active un segundo botón pero en el mismo Activity?

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el siguiente codigo en el onCreate

```
segundoBoton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) //Tambien puedes hacerlo desde XML
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Si quieres que el boton se esconda
       view.setEnabled(false); //Si quieres que el boton se deshabilite      

       segundoBoton.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE) //Para hacer que el segundo boton aparezca 
    }
 });
```

Este código lo que hace es que el segundo botón no este visible y aparezca al pulsarlo, si quieres que el segundo botón este visible desde el principio, pero este deshabilitado. Utiliza el siguiente código:

```
segundoBoton.setEnabled(false) //También puedes hacerlo desde XML
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Si quieres que el boton se esconda
       view.setEnabled(false); //Si quieres que el boton se deshabilite      

       segundoBoton.setEnabled(true) //Para hacer que el segundo botón aparezca 
    }
 });
```

Comment: Si me funcionaron las 2 formas que me enseñaste. ¡Muchas Gracias!